# In Qweb how to filter data based on a value chosen by the user (odoo)?

Tags: odoo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vjq8c.png)

For portal user, I want the list of field values to appear based on the value chosen by this portal user for example:

If this portal user chooses the country, only institutions in the selected country must appear in the list of institutions  field.

```
publicWidget.registry.portalMedical = publicWidget.Widget.extend({
    selector: '.o_portal_medical',
    events: {
        'change select[name="country_id"]': '_onCountryChange',
        'change select[name="state_id"]': '_onStateChange',
        'change select[name="institution_id"]': '_onInstitutionChange',
    },
    start: function () {
        var def = this._super.apply(this, arguments);

        this.$state = this.$('select[name="state_id"]');
        this.$stateOptions =    this.$state.filter(':enabled').find('option:not(:first)');

        this.$institution = this.$('select[name="institution_id"]');
        this.$institutionOptions = this.$institution.filter(':enabled').find('option:not(:first)');

        this.$doctor = this.$('select[name="doctor_id"]');
        this.$doctorOptions = this.$doctor.filter(':enabled').find('option:not(:first)');
        this._adaptAddressForm();

        return def;
    },


    _adaptAddressForm: function () {
        var $country = this.$('select[name="country_id"]');
        var countryID = ($country.val() || 0);
        this.$stateOptions.detach();
        var $displayedState = this.$stateOptions.filter('[data-country_id=' + countryID + ']');
        var nb = $displayedState.appendTo(this.$state).show().length;
        //this.$state.parent().toggle(nb >= 1);

        var $state = this.$('select[name="state_id"]');
        var stateID = ($state.val() || 0);
        this.$institutionOptions.detach();
        var $displayedInstitution = this.$institutionOptions.filter('[data-state_id=' + stateID + ']');
        var mb =    $displayedInstitution.appendTo(this.$institution).show().length;
        //this.$institution.parent().toggle(mb >= 1);


    },

    _onCountryChange: function () {
        this._adaptAddressForm();
    },

    _onStateChange: function () {
        this._adaptAddressForm();
    },

});
```

Comment: I can't see where you declared states by you can filter them in `foreach` or using `t-if`. try `state.country_id.id == partner.country_id.id`

Comment: Thank you but i solved it by using web.public.widget (Javascript code) to filter institution list based on the state chosen by user **t-att-data-state_id="institution.state_id.id"**

Comment: But know i have another problem in data filtration, the case is: 1. the user select the country 2. based on the chosen country the states list appear 3.base on the value of state chosen by the user a list of institutions will appear (until this step it is working fine) 4. based on value of institution chosen by the user a list of services must appear(each service is related to a institution )  i built another widget but it does not work

Comment: Try to use the same logic in the same widget.